# Why do I get this error: Postman Error: Malformed part header?

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, postman, multer

I am using Postman with these headers.

[image]

If I keep the default Content-Type, it will throw me the error

```
Error: Malformed part header
```

However, if I remove the default Content-Type and put in my own (see the last key), it will NOT be able to scan my uploaded file (`req.file` is `undefined`). If I have any sort of boundary, the same error is thrown.

Thus, I am leaning towards thinking that the boundary is the problem. However, if I remove it, I won't be able to see my `req.file`

Here is my node.js code

```
const multer = require("multer")

const upload = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, callback) => {
            callback(null, "./images")
        },
        filename: (req, file, callback) => {
            callback(null, file.originalname)
        }
    })
})

app.post("/single", upload.single("upload"), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    res.send("Testing123")
})
```

UPDATE:
I have not found the answer yet, but when i closed and reopened postman, the `Error: Malformed part header` No longer shows. However, my `req.file` is still `undefined`

and because someone asked if [another stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182746/postman-for-multipart-form-data) answered my question: nope, it didn't, and here is why. I am already doing Answer 1  [image: Answer 1 , the checked answer]

Answer 3 (`multipart/mixed`) also makes my `req.file` `undefined`

I watched the video from Answer 4 but it's the same as answer one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [POSTMAN for Multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182746/postman-for-multipart-form-data)

Comment: @Onboardmass nope. the `req.file` is still `undefined` . That post was one of the first I stumbled upon actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was pretty stupid. For some reason, it doesn't show req.file, BUT it still processes all the same. It really confused me, but I changed my code to the official multer error handling way,
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#error-handling

```
app.post('/profile', function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
    } else if (err) {
      // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
    } else {
    // Everything went fine.
      console.log(req.file)
    }

  })
})
```

i would be able to see it under `//Everything went fine` portion. It's a bit weird, so if anyone knows the reason why, please tell me

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Postman as well, i switched to Insomnia and my code worked just fine. The problem appears to be postman and not multer.

Comment: Since this doesn't explain much, it might be more appropriate as a comment than answer

Comment: Since this doesn't explain much, it might be more appropriate as a comment than answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32335264)

Comment: What more do you need? CCTV footage??

Answer (score 0):

**Malformed part header**
This error occurs in the postman. This is a postman glitch.(By this method I solved this problem so I am sharing)
first of all you have to check the headers properly if all well. 1) Then delete the request you have made in the postman collection. 2) Then make or add a new request and hit the request it should work.

Comment: Hi, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Posting well formatted and focused answers is a strict requirement on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Yes I confirm that it's a glitch from postman,
the solution for me is just deleting the request in my collection and re-configured it and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Check form code carefully and header:

```
const sinupsubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const myform = new FormData();
  myform.set("name",name);
  myform.set("email", email);
  myform.set("password", password);
  myform.set("avatar", avatar)
  dispatch(register(myform))
}

dispatch({type:USER_REQUEST});
const config = {
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
  },
};
const { data } = await axios.post('/user/register', userdata, config);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Remove your "enter" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWE4v.png)

Im my case, I just press here NOT needed "enter" button.
Just remove it from here.